# Is @Order really needed in Spring Boot 2.0.4 OAuth server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have this little OAuth server class and I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4 and the `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` 2.0.0.RELEASE dependency :

```
@RestController 
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(200) // really needed ?
public class MyOAuthServerApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @RequestMapping({ "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails mary =
             User.withUsername("mary")
                .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$B3NUb0x.MYnSfx7WJItrvO/ymEQwLCKQNehmCuA8keL1uTyHizI0i")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(mary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyOAuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This seems to work well with and without the `@Order(200)` annotation.

So is this annotation really needed ?

Comment: There are many Order annotations can you please tell us the package name?

Comment: It's `org.springframework.core.annotation.Order` - which other Order annotations are there ?

Answer (score 1):

The Order annotation is used to define the injection precedence.
Read more her: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order

In your case it's because of the EnableResourceServer annotation. And you must keep the annotation.

From the doc:

> The @EnableResourceServer annotation creates a security filter with
>   @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER-1) by default, so by
>   moving the main application security to
>   @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) we ensure that the
>   rule for "/me" takes precedence.

Please find the tutorial here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: Not sure about the advice to delete it. The documentation of `@EnableResourceServer` server states: 'The annotation creates a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a hard-coded Order (of 3)' - shouldn't the Order of the main class then be greater to take precedence ?

Comment: You are right! I changed my answer and added a link to the tutorial

Comment: For some reason `SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER` does not exist anymore in Spring Boot 2.0.4 which confuses me a bit - do you know why ?

Comment: Also, if I delete the annotation, everything seems to work just as fine. So the question remains ...

Answer (score 0):

You need it if you have another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration.

For example if you allow users to login via login form with a different `UserDetailsService` and so on. Then this should be tried before your oauth authentification and thus needs a lower order, for example `@Order(199)`.

Another example would be different configuration for your API access.

If you don't have any other configuration, then you don't need to set the order.

Setting the order to 200 also seems to be an arbitrary value, that should simply be higher then the others and thus executed last.